# FluentNHibernate HasManyToMany syntax

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[User](
    [UserID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [UserName] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Password] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_User] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [UserID] ASC
) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Module](
    [ModuleID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ModuleName] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Module] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ModuleID] ASC
) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Role](
    [RoleID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [RoleName] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Role] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [RoleID] ASC
) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[UserRoleSetting](
    [UserID] [int] NOT NULL, /* FK to User table */
    [ModuleID] [int] NOT NULL, /* FK to Module table */
    [RoleID] [int] NOT NULL, /* FK to Role table */
 CONSTRAINT [PK_UserRoleSetting] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [UserID] ASC,
    [ModuleID] ASC
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
```

I have a schema like this to define the users have different roles under different modules. I know if UserRoleSetting table is just a simple many to many relationship table, it is easy to define. But that table actually contains relationship from 3 different tables, so what might be the correct syntax to load user role settings into user object?

Thanks

Hardy

Answer (score 1):

What you would like to map is a three-way many-to-many.

You can't define it directly. You instead create a separate entity UserRoleSetting and map it using: one-to-manys in User, Module, Role and many-to-one in UserRoleSetting. In FluentNHibernate it translates into HasMany() and References() respectively.

You can omit one side of the mapping of each connection if bi-directionality is not needed.

Does that solve your problem?